# Assign value to column based on another character column

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I have a data frame that look like this:

```
    df <- data.frame(subject = c(a1_1, a1_1, a1_1, a1_1, a1_2, a1_2, b1_1, b1_1),
 group = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA)
```

as you can see only the first entry of every `subject` has a `group` assigned. My idea is fill the blank spaces of every `subject` with the `group` number(e.g. all a1_1 must have a group 1 value).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When running your code I get `object 'a1_1' not found`. Did you mean "a1_1" un quotes ? Can you show what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may do

```
df$group <- match(df$subject, unique(df$subject))
```

-output

```
> df
   subject group
1     a1_1     1
2     a1_1     1
3     a1_1     1
4     a1_1     1
5     a1_2     2
6     a1_2     2
7     b1_1     3
8     b1_1     3
9     b1_1     3
10    b1_1     3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(subject = c("a1_1", "a1_1", "a1_1", "a1_1", "a1_2", 
"a1_2", "b1_1", "b1_1", "b1_1", "b1_1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always structured the same way, you can pull the group assignment out of the subject information:

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(subject = c(rep('a1_1', 4), rep('a1_2', 2), rep('b1_1',4)))
df$group <- str_sub(df$subject, -1)
```

The str_sub pulls out the last element of the character to assign to the group, assuming it's the last character you want.